# "No ad to show" for AdMob's Native Express ad

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, admob

I have set up at Native Express Ad in AdMob, initialized it in the AppDelegate, and have set up the adViews. I am 100% sure I had the app ID and ad unit ID correct. However when I try to load the request for the ad, it  always says "No ad to show". I have seen similar answers warn that the size of the ad is incompatible, but I have tried MANY sizes within the "small" Native Express Template. None work. I have followed the Google Mobile Garage tutorial to set these up to the letter. I am using these two methods to create and load the ads:

```
func injectNativeAds() {
    var index = 0
    let altSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: self.tableView.frame.width * 0.75, height: 100))
    print(altSize.size)
    while index < tableViewSource.count {
        let adView = GADNativeExpressAdView(adSize: altSize)
        adView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXX/XXXXX"
        adView?.rootViewController = self
        adView?.delegate = self
        tableViewSource.insert(adView!, at: index)
        adsToLoad.append(adView!)
        index += adInterval
    }
}

func preloadNextAd() {
    if !adsToLoad.isEmpty {
        print("Loading ad!")
        let ad = adsToLoad.removeFirst()
        print("Ad size that is laoding: \(ad.adSize.size)")
        let req = GADRequest()
        req.testDevices = ["306f26a33aca5bb1d39124f1c1c2944c", "cdec0a3b2d0b4e72f15f3c6f3a02da29"]
        ad.load(req)
    }
}
```

Nothing works. No test ads either. What am I doing wrong? I see a lot of people having similar issues but no answers.

Comment: did you get this print ("Ad size that is laoding: \(ad.adSize.size)") ?

Comment: Yes. It prints 572 by 100